# My Notebook VGA output port sends Logon Background Image, but not what is showing on scrn

Tags: drivers

My Acer 1810T Notebook will display the logon background image all the time and not the image that is currently showing on the screen when screen is viewed thru the Acer's VGA output port.  Trying to output to a projector with a VGA input.

Answer (score 1):

set the displays to MIRROR in the settings